# Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements in BigQuery

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I am working on Python code to execute BigQuery sql command using bigquery.Client.query. I am getting **Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements** exception.

Below is the Python code I am using

```
if query_file_name:
    with open(query_file_name, mode="r") as query_file:
        query = query_file.read()

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.use_legacy_sql = use_legacy_sql

if destination:
    if destination.partitioned_field:
        job_config.time_partitioning = TimePartitioning(type_=TimePartitioningType.DAY, 
                                         field=destination.partitioned_field)
google_bq_table = self.fetch_table_reference(destination)
job_config.destination = google_bq_table

job_config.write_disposition = WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND

query_job = self.google_client.query(query, job_config=job_config)  # API request - starts the query asynchronously
```

I have query_file as in below BigQuery sql

```
INSERT mydataset.target_table
        (col1, col2, col3, created_date)
WITH T AS (SELECT col1, col2, col3, CURRENT_DATE() as created_date
            from mydataset.temp_table
           )
SELECT col1, col2, col3, created_date FROM T
```

Appreciate your help in advance

Thanks,

Raghunath.

Comment: Check out this question which looks similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/q/55166634/1031958 and let us know if this solves your problem

Comment: @TamirKlein Thanks for sharing, I am executing 2 queries which are dependent. which can't be executed separately. Can you please help to overcome this issue

Comment: Ok, so Reading your code example after another review I'm not sure I understand your use case. You are inserting INTO a table but you also saved the result in a destination table `job_config.destination = google_bq_table`, What is the reason for that?

Comment: @TamirKlein: Thanks for the question. I am new to BigQuery. I have written code which is trying to insert data into same table two times. I have removed INSERT mydataset.target_table (col1, col2, col3, created_date), which resolved the issue.

Comment: Great, For others to see I posted an answer which will be great if you can accept and vote-up. Glad to hear my answer helped you.

Answer (score 6):

> Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements

As stat in BigQuery error message, you can't set in your python code destination object when running an insert command.

Removing this lines

```
if destination:
    if destination.partitioned_field:
        job_config.time_partitioning = TimePartitioning(type_=TimePartitioningType.DAY, 
                                         field=destination.partitioned_field)
google_bq_table = self.fetch_table_reference(destination)
job_config.destination = google_bq_table
```

from your code will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery should be below one rather than the one in the question. With below query I am able to load data successfully to target table.

```
WITH T AS (SELECT col1, col2, col3, CURRENT_DATE() as created_date
            from mydataset.temp_table
           )
SELECT col1, col2, col3, created_date FROM T
```