# Error "Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements" even though I'm not setting the destination table

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have the following code which I'm using to select data from one bigquery table and insert into another, after first deleting data in the destination:

```py
#delete
sql = """
delete from `b` 
where _date_ = '2019-10-24'
"""
query_job = client.query(sql)
results = query_job.result()

#insert
sql = """
insert into `b` (col1,col2) 
select col1, col2 from a
where a._date_ = '2019-10-24'
"""
query_job = client.query(sql)
results = query_job.result()
```

It runs successfully. However, I want to parameterise the date that I run for so I've followed the examples at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries and changed it to this:

```py
query_params = [
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("_date_", "STRING", "2019-10-24")
]
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.query_parameters = query_params

#delete
sql = """
delete from `b` 
where _date_ = @_date_
"""
query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)
results = query_job.result()

#insert
sql = """
insert into `b` (col1,col2)
select col1, col2 from a
where a._date_ = @_date_
"""
query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)
results = query_job.result()
```

This now fails with error on the insertion:

> Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements

The deletion worked fine!

I've googled around and discovered examples (e.g. [Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55511304/cannot-set-destination-table-in-jobs-with-dml-statements-in-bigquery)) of this error occurring when the destination table is specified in the `job_config`, but I am not doing that, so I'm a little confused.

Why does my supplying a query parameter cause the code to fail with this error?

Comment: I think you need to reset the `job_config` after the first query. Can you try that and see?

Comment: Hi Elliott, nice to see you on here instead of twitter for a change :)  I can try, what do you mean by reset? Just declare it again?

Comment: Yeah, just try assigning `job_config` itself plus the query parameters prior to running the next statement. If I remember correctly, I think that the `job_config` that you pass into `client.query` gets modified.

Comment: Thank you @ElliottBrossard, that worked. If you post your comment as an answer I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Great, I'm glad that it worked! Added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that running a DML statement updates the destination table within the `job_config` that you pass to `client.query`. You need to reset it in between like this:

```
query_params = [
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("_date_", "STRING", "2019-10-24")
]
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.query_parameters = query_params

#delete
sql = """
delete from `b` 
where _date_ = @_date_
"""
query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)
results = query_job.result()

# reset config
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.query_parameters = query_params

#insert
sql = """
insert into `b` (col1,col2)
select col1, col2 from a
where a._date_ = @_date_
"""
query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)
results = query_job.result()
```